# Python averaging with ndarrays, csvfile data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In a folder, I have a number of `.csv` files (count varies) each of which has 5 rows and 1200 columns of numerical data(`float`).

Now I want to average the data in these files (i.e. `R1C1` of files gives one averaged value in a resulting file, and so on for every position (`R2C2` of all files gives one value in the same position of resulting file etc.).

How do I sequentially `input` all files in that folder into a couple of arrays; what functions in `numpy` can be used to just find the mean among the files (now arrays) that have been read into these arrays. Is there a better way to this? New to computing, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're certainly on the right track (because `python` together with `numpy` is a great combination for this task), but in order to do what you want to do, you do need some basic programming skills. I'll assume you at least know a little about working in an interactive `python` shell and how to import modules etc. `:-)`

Then probably the easiest approach is to only have a single `numpy` array: one that contains the sum of the data in your files. After that it's just a matter of dividing by the number of files that you have.

So for example you could follow the following approach:

- loop over all files in a folder with a `for`-loop and the `os.listdir` method
- check if the file belongs to the data collection, for example by using something like `str.endswith('.csv')`
- convert the filename to a full path by using `os.path.join`
- read the data to a `numpy` array with `numpy.loadtxt`
- add this data to the array containing the sums, which is initialized with `np.zeros` before the loop
- keep a count of how many files you processed
- after the loop, calculate the means by dividing the sums by the number of files processed